# Database doesn't Update - PHP Form through MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql

I'm currently trying to get a database updated through a PHP form. Firstly I get all the information from the database within the form, and then trying to  update details within that form to reflect on the database.

I could successfully managed to get all the details from the database within the form but unfortunately doesn't update for that reason.

Here is the code to retrieve the info from DB, within the form which works 100%:

```
include_once 'db_connect.php';

if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<form id=updateVehicle action='' method=post";
            echo "<div id='vehicleDescription'>";

                echo "<div>";
                    echo "<label for=vin>VIN</label>";
                    echo "<input type=text id=vin name=vin minlength=17 maxlength=17 placeholder=e.g. BMW1234567890ABCD value="  . $row['vin'] . " />";
                    echo "<br/>";
                echo "</div>";

                echo "<div>";
                    echo "<label for=make>Make</label>";
                    echo "<input type=text id=make name=make minlength=3 maxlength=13 placeholder=e.g. BMW value=" . $row['make'] . " />";
                    echo "<br/>";
                echo "</div>";

                echo "<div>";
                    echo "<label for=model>Model</label>";
                    echo "<input type=text id=model name=model minlength=2 maxlength=15 placeholder=e.g. 530D value=" . $row['model'] . " />";
                    echo "<br/>";
                echo "</div>";

               echo "<div>";
                    echo "<input type=text name=id value=" . $row['id'] . " />";
                echo "</div>";

                echo "<span><?php echo $errorMessage;?></span>";
            echo "</div> <!--End of vehicleDescription div-->";
            echo "<input type='submit' class='submit' value='Update Ads' />";
        echo "</form>";
    }
}
```

The action is empty because it submits to itself, I've tried to use "echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);" but it didn't work, so I left it out.

Here is the code to process the update which doesn't work:

```
if(isset($_POST['vin'], $_POST['make'], $_POST['model'])) {
    $vin = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'vin', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $make = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'make', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $model = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'model', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);

    if($insert_stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE vehicles SET (vin=?, make=?, model=? WHERE id=? ")) {
        $insert_stmt->bind_param("sssi", $vin, $make, $model, $id);

        if(!$insert_stmt->execute()) {
            header('Location: ../error.php?err=Registration failure: UPDATE');
            $mysqli->close();
        }
    }
    header('Location: ../includes/register_success.php');
    $mysqli->close();
}
```

For some unknown reasons to me, it doesn't update the database at all. The 'db_connect.php' works 100% as I'm using it for other database queries.

I'd really appreciate any help if you could point me in the right direction.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you get any errors in your error_log? And what happens if you try to echo `$vin $make $model $id` after sanitizing them?

Comment: Lose the parentheses?

Comment: Hi Qirel, Whenever I try to active the error log, I will end up with "Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in...". However, if the error reporting is turned off the code executes as it should, apart the code which doesn't work as mentioned above. Also, when I echo those variables nothing happens. Presumably the variables aren't set? Thank you

Comment: Hi Drew Pierce, I tried to remove them but still no luck. Any other suggestions? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you getting an error when executing the update query? I can see an extra **(** after **SET** in:

```
UPDATE vehicles SET (vin=?, make=?, model=? WHERE id=?
```

This should cause the query to fail which is a good reason why things are not updated in the database.

Comment: He doesn't have error reporting turned on or care to look at log

Comment: Hi jedrzej.kurylo, I tried to remove the parentheses you mentioned above but still no luck. Any other suggestion? Thank you

Comment: Hi Drew Pierce, Whenever I configure the PHP Error Log I will end up with "Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in...". If I comment out the error log from PHP.ini, the code works fine, well apart the one mentioned above. Do you have any idea why is that? Thank you

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php you are missing mysqli extension

Comment: I've double checked that and has been uncommented from the php.ini. However, if I turn the error reporting off, the code executes as it should and no problems there. The problem appears only when turn on the error reporting

Comment: Enabling  error reporting won't break anything, it will just, well, enable error reporting :) Could you paste the whole "Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in..." error message and the piece of code that is mentioned in the error message?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Sure, here it is: Fatal error: Class 'mysqli' not found in C:\Apache24\htdocs\Project\includes\db_connect.php on line 4. Line 4 being: "$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USER, PASSWORD, DATABASE);". Thank you

Comment: And you're saying that logic that displays the form works and displays data from the database? Could you update the question with db_connect.php? I don't see where the $result variable is set.

Comment: Yes it works, as long as I turn the error reporting off. The $result is set at the top "$result = $stmt->get_result();"

Comment: Sure, please update the answer with all 3 files: db_connect, the file that displays the form, the file that handles the post data. Maybe I'll see something there, so far I've run out of ideas.

Comment: Please also check what is diisplayed by: <?php var_dump(extension_loaded('mysqli')); die();

Comment: And <?php phpinfo(); die();

Comment: By running <?php phpinfo(); die(); it displays the PHP version with all the configs, and by running <?php var_dump(extension_loaded('mysqli')); die(); it says "bool(true)

Comment: Ok, so we know you have the extension loaded. What about those 3 files?

Comment: Uh ... Sorted! Finally! I thought would be better if I will rewrite everything and worked! Thank you so much for your help. You're a star